# Showing the lowest pid / parent id number first

Tags: codeigniter

I have this function below which get the pid numbers from my database. The pid is parent id.

```
public function test() {
    $arr = array();

    foreach ($this->make_parent_list() as $result) {
        $arr[] = $result;
    }

    print_r(implode(',', $arr));

}
```

The out put is as follows 4, 1

**But I need it to print the lowest number first. 1, 4**

> Question How can I make sure when i view the parent id / pid that it
>   will show the lowest number first I have tried
>   `$this->db->order_by('pid', 'desc');` and `$this->db->order_by('pid',
>   'asc');`

```
public function make_parent_list() {
    $this->db->where('fid', '5');

    $query = $this->db->get('forum');

    $return = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $category)
    {
        $this->db->where('fid', $category->pid);
        $this->db->order_by('pid', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get('forum');

        $return[$category->pid] = $category->pid;

        foreach ($query->result() as $category)
        {

        $return[$category->pid] = $category->pid;

        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: And pid = 0 is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

I had to created a $results variable and then wrap in sort() outside foreach loop

```
$arr = array();

$results = $this->make_parent_list();

sort($results);

foreach ($results as $result) {
   $arr[] = $result;
}

echo implode(',', $arr);
```

> Now out put 1,4

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a bit lost... The order_by asc,desc does work. Your function has order_by desc and an unnecessary foreach etc.

Assumptions: The forum table has at least the two columns pid and fid. I created a table with

```
fid , pid
5     1
5     4
```

If you simplify your function to...

```
// Given the fid, return an array of pid values in ascending order
public function make_parent_list() {
    $this->db->where('fid', '5'); // Hardcoded for testing.
    $this->db->order_by('pid', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get('forum');
    $pid_list = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $category) {
        $pid_list[] = $category->pid;
    }

    return $pid_list;
}
```

Then you only need

```
$results = $this->make_parent_list();
echo implode(',', $results);
```

That will give you a result of 1,4.

If you change asc to desc in the order_by in the function then you will get 4,1.

Comment: Could not make it work because I have foreach inside foreach to get the any sub id

Comment: I could not make it to work when I have sub categorys I have updated my question with example down bottom of question

Comment: Ahh well that is a different Kettle of Fish all together BUT in your question you had fid set to 5 and your output is 1,4 So what you have stated in your original question conflicts with your updates to the question.

Comment: The 1, 4 were just examples

Comment: Ok since it conflicts with question I have removed examples will work it out later thanks